# Javascript library for dynamically switching pages/views

Tags: javascript, nagios, rrdtool, graphic-effects

I have been using nagios + pnp4nagios for a while and am happy with the images rrdtool creates. My current task is to create a panel that has some statistics generated by nagios and after a while the statistics change. I'm looking for something like that: [image]

But also able to switch screens automatically. I do know that I can make a timed javascript function that switches the layout after a determined time, but I also want to add effects and other stuff to the picture. Any good javascript library that has it?

Comment: No, I haven't. I usually get only one answer and I always find it incomplete. I won't accept an answer unless I am actually willing to use it in my code. As I haven't found such an answer / piece of code up to now, I, naturally, haven't accepted any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

such effects can be achieved easily with most javascript libraries. I like jQuery quite well. See the examples in [link text](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) for inspiration

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end I ended up used Adobe's Spry Effects. I am quite familiar with JQuery and Sencha, but I was looking for a more dedicated (and compact) decision. Still, if I had to choose a favorite javascript library, it would definitely be Sencha.

Comment: I will wait for one day for somebody to post an alternative answer and am then accepting your answer.

Comment: By the way, I just noticed who answered my question. I am a HUGE fan! Keep up the amazing work!